# d3 wordcloud fontsize doesn't adapt

Tags: d3.js, font-size, word-cloud

the fontsize of my d3.wordcloud document isn't affected by it's count as specified in the wordlist.tsv file. However from what I understand of the code it should be.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Word Cloud Example</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<script>
 var width = 500; heigth = 500;



var wordscale = d3.scale.linear().range([10,60]);
 var fill = d3.scale.category20();
        d3.tsv("wordlist.tsv",function(data){
        var wordlist2 = data
                .filter(function(d){ return +d.count > 10;})
                .map(function(d){ return{text: d.word +" ("+ d.count+")", fsize: +d.count};})
                .sort(function(a,b){return d3.descending(a.fsize,b.fsize);})
                .slice(0,100);



        wordscale.domain([0,d3.max(wordlist2, function(d) {return d.fsize;})]);
            d3.layout.cloud()
                .size([width, heigth]) 
                .padding(1)
                .words(wordlist2) 
                .rotate(0)
                .fontSize(function(d) { return wordscale(+d.fsize); })
                .on("end", draw) //afblijven
                .start(); //start algoritme
});


function draw(words) {
   d3.select("body")
          .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", heigth)
                .attr("class", "wordcloud")
              .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate("+width/2+","+heigth/2+")")
                .selectAll("text")
                .data(words)
              .enter().append("text")
                .style("font-size", function(d) { d.fsize + "px"; })
                .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
                .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";})
                .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
    }

</script>
</html>
```

from what i understand the following line of code:

```
.fontSize(function(d) { return wordscale(+d.fsize); })
```

should adapt the code to the scale as defined earlier in the code, but alas it doesn't and all the words are the same size. Altough the count parameter is different for each word in the .tsv file

any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, i forgot a return statement in the following line of code

```
.style("font-size", function(d) { d.fsize + "px"; })
```

this should be:

```
.style("font-size", function(d) {return d.fsize + "px"; })
```